# "Do-er" classes versus static utility methods

Tags: java, oop

Say you have the `FileReader` class with a `read` method.

I understand that class-level attributes can justify having an instance. However, what is stopping making an equivalent `ReaderUtils` class by pulling these same attributes inside the scope of a corresponding `static` `read` method ?

In short, what exactly justifies a "Doer" class with respect to static utility methods ?

Comment: Nothing is stopping anyone from making an equivalent `ReaderUtils`, in fact, it is implemented in the JRE: [`Files.readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of OOP is encapsulating state/data along with associated behaviour. Static utility methods are akin to global functions in a procedural language -- you are separating behaviour (the static method) from state (the parameters to this method), thereby breaking encapsulation.

What does this mean in practice? Instead of being able to call `reader.read()`, you have to call `ReaderUtils.read(file)`, which means you are now tightly coupled to the implementation -- you have made an implicit assumption that you will always use `ReaderUtils` and always pass in a file.

If you instead use the generic `Reader` interface, you can use a `FileReader` today but swap it out for a `DatabaseReader` or a `HttpReader` tomorrow without having to change any other code -- all the `reader.read()` calls will continue to work the same.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces can't be implemented statically - the implemented methods of an interface must be *instance* methods. As such, this prohibits [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or [JNDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) lookup of a "utility class" as the runtime implementation to perform some service - it must be an *instance* of a class. This is one of the main reasons why "doer" classes exist.

Utility classes are fine if the implementation is known at compile time, and being static methods they are more likely to naturally be stateless (just make sure any static fields are immutable/stateless), which is required by typical servers that serve requests concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of preference. In general, Java favors nouns (because people feel this is more OO) therefore FileReader.

As noted by Jeffrey, sometimes the noun obsession leads to unnecessary verbosity at which point calls get wrapped in static methods.

Comment: Not 100% relevant, but this reminds me of how people love factories so much in Java... http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/server/RequestProcessorFactoryFactory